# Disable SSL when unit testing

Tags: php, cakephp, ssl, phpunit

I have that code in my AppController which enables the SSL for the applicaiton only when it's not in debug mode.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {


        if (!Configure::read('debug')) {
            $this->Security->requireSecure();
        }
    }
```

I want to disable the SSL when I am executing uni tests.

I tried to define a bool constant in bootstrap file of PHPUnit and then check if it's true in AppController, but unfortunately can't access constants defined from phpunit/bootstrap outside of phpunit.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `but that unfortunately can't access constants defined from phpunit/bootstrap`- are you testing with curl calls or something? You would normally account for that by mocking the security component, not changing your application code. See the docs for [testAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers) for more info or *update the question* to clarify what the problem is (e.g. by adding your test method code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself

In tests/bootstrap.php I added:

```
define('TEST', true);
```

Then in AppController:

```
   //Disable validation of post requests
    $this->Security->Config('validatePost', false);

    if (!Configure::read('debug') && !defined ('TEST')) {
        $this->Security->requireSecure();
    }
```

And that worked for me.

Comment: Why down-voting ? Question is not " Should I disable SSL when unit testing ?", the question is "Disable SSL when unit testing". So I guess I estimated all those risks for code going in production by delegating that to the underlying framework...